# How to conduct an effective literature survey in mathematics?

Tags: mathematics, literature-search

Due to Covid, I am unable to go to my University and access the University server. As a result I am unable to use MathSciNet. Is there any other way to do a good and effective literature survey on a topic in Mathematics?

If someone could help me,  I would be  grateful. I am also interested to know how researchers working at Universities that don't have a MathSciNet license conduct research?

Comment: Indirect answer only (if that). Can your university librarian or department chair inquire about or arrange for remote mathscinet access?

Comment: I probably haven't used MathSciNet for over a decade. Google Scholar has been totally adequate for my needs. Is there some specific reason Scholar is not working for you?

Comment: It's unlikely that your university has no way for you to remotely connect to MathSciNet. Ask you reference librarian.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simple answer: There are actually *two* good and well-known (at least, I had thought so) bibliographic databases for mathematical literature:

- MathSciNet
- [zbMATH](https://zbmath.org/)

The latter is freely available online as of 2021.

(Of course there are a few differences between them - for instance, the quality of the bibtex entries is a bit better in MathSciNet, in my experience. But anyway, for most purposes both databases do their job quite well.)

**Historical Note:** While MathSciNet is essentially based on *Mathematical Reviews*, zbMATH is based on the *Zentralblatt für Mathematik* - and both the *Zentralblatt* and *Mathematical Reviews* were founded by the same person, [Otto Neugebauer](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Neugebauer/). I would have called this a fun fact, but unfortunately the historically background (which is described in the previous link) is not particularly funny.